# How to Avoid Duplicate ID's In Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, duplicates

I have a  problem that I hope you can help me.

I have the next query on Access SQL.

```
SELECT 
    ID_PLAN_ACCION, ID_SEGUIMIENTO, 
    Max(FECHA_SEGUIMIENTO) AS MAX_FECHA
FROM 
    SEGUIMIENTOS
WHERE 
   (((ID_PLAN_ACCION) = [CODPA]))
GROUP BY 
   ID_PLAN_ACCION, ID_SEGUIMIENTO;
```

And it returns this information:

```
ID_PLAN_ACCION  ID_SEGUIMIENTO  MAX_FECHA
-----------------------------------------------    
A1-01                  1             16/01/2014
A1-01                  2             30/01/2014
```

But I really need that it throws off this:

```
ID_PLAN_ACCION  ID_SEGUIMIENTO  MAX_FECHA
----------------------------------------------    
A1-01                  2             30/01/2014
```

As you can see I only need the record that has the most recently date, not all the records

The `GROUP BY` doesn't work.

Please can you tell me what can I do? I am new on all this.

Thank you so much!!

PD: Sorry for my english, I'm learning

Comment: Have you tried to only group by ID_PLAN_ACCION, as the additional group by will cause the further split I believe?

Comment: Try removing ID_SEGUIMIENTO in your GROUP BY you will get the expected result.                                                SELECT ID_PLAN_ACCION, ID_SEGUIMIENTO, Max(FECHA_SEGUIMIENTO) AS MAX_FECHA
FROM SEGUIMIENTOS
WHERE (((ID_PLAN_ACCION)=[CODPA]))
GROUP BY ID_PLAN_ACCION;

Answer (score 2):

This will produce the results you want:

```
SELECT ID_PLAN_ACCION, max(ID_SEGUIMIENTO) as ID_SEGUIMIENTO, Max(FECHA_SEGUIMIENTO) AS MAX_FECHA
FROM SEGUIMIENTOS
WHERE  ID_PLAN_ACCION = [CODPA]
GROUP BY ID_PLAN_ACCION;
```

I removed `id_sequiimiento` from the `group by` and added an aggregation function to get the max value.  If the `id`s increase along with the date, this will work.

Another way to approach this query, though, is to use `top` and `order by`:

```
SELECT top 1 ID_PLAN_ACCION, ID_SEGUIMIENTO, FECHA_SEGUIMIENTO
FROM SEGUIMIENTOS
WHERE  ID_PLAN_ACCION = [CODPA]
ORDER BY FECHA_SEGUIMIENTO desc;
```

This works because you are only returning one row.

EDIT:

If you have more codes, that you are looking at, you need a more complicated query.  Here is an approach using `where`/`not exists`:

```
SELECT ID_PLAN_ACCION, ID_SEGUIMIENTO, FECHA_SEGUIMIENTO
FROM SEGUIMIENTOS s
WHERE  not exists (select 1
                   from SEGUIMIENTOS s2
                   where s.ID_PLAN_ACCION = s2.ID_PLAN_ACCION and
                         s2.FECHA_SEGUIMIENTO > s.FECHA_SEGUIMIENTO
                  )
ORDER BY FECHA_SEGUIMIENTO desc;
```

You can read this as:  "Get me all rows from SEGUIMIENTOS where there is no other row with the same ID_PLAN_ACCION that has a larger date".  Is is another way of saying that the original row has the maximum date.

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon, The top 1 works perfect in this case. But what happens if I have more codes on ID_PLAN_ACCION for example A1-01, A2-02, A3-03. And each one has several records. For example A1-01 has : 16/01/2014, 30/01/2014. A2-02 has : 07/02/2014 And A3-03 : 09/01/2014, 24/12/2013, 12/02/2014. And I need that it returns this:
A1-01: 30/01/2014,  A2-02:07/02/2014  and A3-03 :12/02/2014.
The ids don't increase along with the date.
Thank you again! :)

Comment: Thank you Gordon, and what happens if I have mixed tables with inner joins instead a simple table?
Does it work anyway?
Can I give an alias to a inner join for do this?